# PHP Loop 1 to 800 separating every 5 lines

Tags: php, loops

I need to achieve this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
---
6
7
8
9
10
---
11
12
13
14
15
---
16
17
18
19
20
---
...
800
```

my code:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$str = '';
for($i = 1; $i<=800; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + $i;
    $str .= $i == 5 ? $i. "<br> --- <br>": $i."<br>";
}
echo $str;
```

the problem is that with this code it only managed to divide after the first block.

I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use modulus operator `%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$sum = 0;
$str = '';
for($i = 1; $i<=800; $i++) {
    $sum = $sum + $i;
    $str .= $i%5 == 0 ? $i. "<br> --- <br>": $i."<br>";
}
echo $str;
```

just change `$i == 5` into `$i%5 == 0`

Comment: Last line can be simplified to: `$str .= $i . ($i%5 ? '' : "<br> ---"  )  . "<br>";`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a much easier way:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i<=800; $i++) {
    echo $i . "\n";
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        echo "---\n";
    }
}
```

This is meant for CLI output, but HTML basically works the same.